# How to create a button in QTreeView with Delegate?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qtreeview, qstyleditemdelegate

I have a table like this:

[image]

When I move the mouse over a row of that table, there is a button in the right hand side of the row, and when I click onto that button, that row will be deleted from the table.

[image]

How can I adjust my delegate and signal/slot in my view for this requirement?

```
void ItemDelegate::paint( QPainter *p_painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &p_option, const QModelIndex &p_index ) const
{
  QStyleOptionViewItem option = p_option;

  QString text = p_index.data( Qt::DisplayRole ).toString();
  int col = p_index.column();

  if ( option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver )
  {
      p_painter->fillRect( p_option.rect, Qt::green );
      p_painter->setPen(Qt::white);
  }
  else
  {
      p_painter->setPen(Qt::black);
  }

  if ( col == 0 )
  {
      option.rect.setRect( option.rect.left() + 20, option.rect.top(), option.rect.width() - 10, option.rect.height() );
  }
  else
  {
      option.rect.setRect( option.rect.left() + 10, option.rect.top(), option.rect.width() - 10, option.rect.height() );
  }

  p_painter->drawText( option.rect, Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::TextWordWrap, text );
}
```

The image for X button is `x_button.png`

Comment: For handling clicks on your tree view items you don't need a delegate. You just need to handle `QAbstractItemView::clicked()` signal of your tree view and remove the corresponding row in the slot.

Comment: @vahancho: thanks. But what i need is: when i click onto the row (anywhere but the x button), then the data in the row will be filled into somewhere else (Ex: into a LineEdit). The row should ONLY be removed when I click onto X button.

Comment: @htmlamateur QTreeView or QTableView?on the other hand: does that code that shows work?

Comment: @eyllanesc: QTreeView and this code is just the basic of my source code. The thing I did not post here is just set alignment for first column and second column.

Comment: @htmlamateur my question goes in the sense if it changes the color when mouse passes over the item, does the color change?

Comment: Yes, it changed. :)

Comment: change `Qt:green` to `Qt::green`, please avoid the typos.

Comment: I just tried and only change the color of the item to green when the item is clicked, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I have typing mistake. I did not notice it. In this case, when the mouse is over the cell then the color changes already, because I used `option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver`